# Find attribute of parent element using a known element

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet, xmllint

Not sure if the title is clear but basically I have some XML like the following:

```
<details>
<result id=1234567890>
    <name>Test1</name>
</result>
<result id=5345345433>
    <name>Test2</name>
</result>
<result id=9572385354>
    <name>Test3</name>
</result>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to find the id attribute of  using the known value of 
i.e. Test1 > 1234567890, Test2 > 5345345433, Test3 > 9572385354

Preferably by using xmllint but xmlstarlet is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

**Input**

First, your XML is invalid. Your id properties need to be qouted, and the details is not closed. Here is the  revised input:

```
<details>
  <result id="1234567890">
    <name>Test1</name>
  </result>
  <result id="5345345433">
    <name>Test2</name>
  </result>
  <result id="9572385354">
    <name>Test3</name>
  </result>
</details>
```

**Result**

The following will extract the specific id given the name property using xmlstarlet.

```
 xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/details/result[name='Test1']" test.xml | grep -Po "(?<=id=\")[\d]*"
```

This will return

```
 1234567890
```

You can also replace Test1 in the command with a variable.

```
 var=Test1
 xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/details/result[name='$var']" test.xml | grep -Po "(?<=id=\")[\d]*"
```

**Breakdown**

```
 xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/details/result[name='$var']" test.xml
```

Select all name tags inside results matching $var.

```
 | grep -Po "(?<=id=\")[\d]*"
```

Pipe the output to grep with Perl Regex to look for the id property and print all containing digits.

Comment: You could probably use the same xpath selector with xmlstarlet as I have in my answer, and remove the `grep`. It is always better to do the processing in one command than parsing xml or json with grep/sed or whatever. Especially when you already use a dedicated parser upstream.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --xpath "string(/details/result[name='Test1']/@id)" yourfile.xml
```

`--xpath`: tells `xmllint` to select using the `xpath` syntax.

Details of the `xpath` selector:

```xml
string(/details/result[name='Test1']/@id)
```

`string()`: Make a string

`/details/result`: select the `result` child element of the `details` element

`[name='Test1']`: containing a `name` node whose value is `Test1`

`/@id`: `id` attribute value (of the `result` element)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple grep & awk solution will work for you.

```
grep -B1 Test1 sample.xml | awk '/id=/{gsub(/[^0-9]+/, "", $0); print $0 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OP's question in full,

```
#/bin/bash
#
# how to use xmllint to get information from specific elements
# REQUIRES libxml2 (sorry Snow Leopard!)

mytestxml='
<details>
    <result id="1234567890">
            <name>Test1</name>
    </result>
    <result id="5345345433">
            <name>Test2</name>
    </result>
    <result id="9572385354">
        <name>Test3</name>
    </result>
</details>
'
echo Test Document is :"$mytestxml"
echo Get the contents of the \''id'\' attribute of a specific \''result'\' element
query=\''string(/details/result[3]/@id)'\'
echo xpath query is "$query"
myresult=$(echo "$mytestxml" | xmllint --xpath 'string(/details/result[3]/@id)' - )
echo info returned is "$myresult"
echo ""

echo Get the specific \''result'\' node whose \''name'\' element is \"Test1\"
query=\''/details/result[name="Test1"]'\'               
echo xpath query is "$query"
myresult=$(echo "$mytestxml" | xmllint --xpath '/details/result[name="Test1"]' - )
echo info returned is "$myresult"
echo ""

echo Get the \''id'\' attribute of the specific \''result'\' node whose \''name'\' element is \"Test1\"
query=\''string(/details/result[name="Test1"]/@id)'\'
echo combined xpath query is "$query"
myresult=$(echo "$mytestxml" | xmllint --xpath 'string(/details/result[name="Test1"]/@id)' - )
echo info returned is "$myresult"
```

1. - Get the contents of the 'id' attribute of a specific 'result' element.

xpath query is :

```
    'string(/details/result[3]/@id)'
```

info returned is : 9572385354

2. - Get the specific 'result' node whose 'name' element is "Test1"

xpath query is :

```
    '/details/result[name="Test1"]'
```

info returned is :

```
    <result id="1234567890">
        <name>Test1</name>
    </result>
```

3. - Get the 'id' attribute of the specific 'result' node whose 'name' element is "Test1"

combined xpath query is :

```
    'string(/details/result[name="Test1"]/@id)'
```

info returned is 1234567890

Hope this proves useful to other's who find this page. :o)